# JSON text in arguments in where clause MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am writing a query and what to take JSON argument in where clause but it gives me an error when I run the query.

```
Error Code: 3141. Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function json_extract: "Missing a comma or '}' after an object member." at position 44.
```

and here is my query

```js
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    ctrData2.CallDetail
WHERE
    JSON_EXTRACT(Attributes, '$.FirstName') = 'Mike';
```

and here is my attribute column in CallDetail's talble

[image]

please tell what i am doing wrong

Comment: The error message claims that `Attributes` column contains invalid/broken JSON value.

Comment: Use `SELECT * FROM CallDetail WHERE JSON_VALID(Attributes) = 0` to get all rows with invalid JSON value.

Comment: json_extract(Attributes, '$.FirstName') as Customer..............now i am trying to get value but giving me the same error

Comment: @SebastianBrosch how can i get value from string>>

Comment: @Tayyab - please provide some example data from `Attributes` column so we can reproduce the error.

Comment: @SebastianBrosch ihave attached the screen shot of Attribute coloumn

Comment: before a month this query was working fine json_extract(Attributes, '$.FirstName') as Customer but now when i run it, it gives error

Comment: @SebastianBrosch i just need FirstName from Attributes String how i will get that?

Comment: You get some rows from this query `SELECT * FROM CallDetail WHERE JSON_VALID(Attributes) = 0`?

Comment: i just get the whole table record

Comment: So your JSON is invalid. You have to fix the JSON value on `Attributes` column before you can use JSON functions. The error message is very clear to find the issue: *"Missing a comma or '}' after an object member." at position 44.*